# Different calculation in SQL Server and Excel

Tags: sql, excel, sql-server-2008, math, excel-2010

This is my formula. I put it in a SQL Server stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @Var01 float
SET @Var01 = 1164.83 * (1 - 3.3387306 * LOG(0.00459418151829729) + 1.426559 * POWER(LOG(0.00459418151829729),2)) / (1 - 3.4680733 * LOG(0.00459418151829729) + 1.8779192 * POWER(LOG(0.00459418151829729), 2) - 0.21223784 * POWER(LOG(0.00459418151829729), 3) - 0.0035814371 * POWER(LOG(0.00459418151829729), 4) - 0.90903163 * POWER(10, -4) * POWER(LOG(0.00459418151829729), 5)) - 459.67
```

The result is: `214.630185149416`

Then I'm trying to compare to excel, the formula as below:

```
=1164.83 * (1 - 3.3387306 * LN(0.00459418151829729) + 1.426559 * (LN(0.00459418151829729)) ^ 2) / (1 - 3.4680733 * LN(0.00459418151829729) + 1.8779192 * (LN(0.00459418151829729)) ^ 2 - 0.21223784 * (LN(0.00459418151829729)) ^ 3 - 0.0035814371 * (LN(0.00459418151829729)) ^ 4 - 0.90903163 * 10 ^ -4 * (LN(0.00459418151829729)) ^ 5) - 459.67
```

The result is: `211.981432072480`

The question is, which one is correct? Any Idea? What the calculation is different?

Comment: LN used in Excel, LOG used in SQL.

Comment: You're using a lot of floating-point numbers, some to 17 decimal places. You're losing precision in the floating point arithmetic, and without checking I'd say the the precision offered by SQL and Excel differs which is why you're getting a discrepancy.

Comment: @All, then what should I do?

Comment: LN is called as natural logarithmic and LOG is called as base-10 logarithmic. Actually both are on it's definition. whether do you want to use LN or LOG? Strict on anyone of the function

Comment: @nawazlj Your comment doesn't make sense.

Comment: @lc. please find definition of ln and log.  ln(x) is defined as the function that takes any positive number x as input and returns the exponent to which the base e must be raised to obtain x. (e denotes the number 2.7182818284590…)

log(x) is defined as the function that takes any positive number x as input and returns the exponent to which the base 10 must be raised to obtain x

Comment: @nawazlj Please read the documentation of both Excel's `LN()` and Sql Server's `LOG()`. You'll find they are both the natural logarithm.

Comment: Guys, If i type on excel =LN(0.00459418151829729) , the result is -5.382964663. In SQL, LOG(0.00459418151829729), the result is -5.38296466345896. If I increase the decimal on excel, the result nothing change, still different.

Comment: @Haminteu Yes I think Sql Server seems to have a whole lot more precision on the constant `e`. Try comparing the values of `EXP(1)` in both.

Comment: @lc. so actually, which one should I trust? sql or excel? And why?

Comment: @Haminteu Oh boy, I guess my vote would be with SQL Server. IIRC by default `float` means `float(53)` which is a whole lot more precision than Excel. You could also try Wolfram Alpha and see what you get there, but you'll have to split your formula into a couple chunks due to the size limit. I'm not confident enough in this to provide an answer though. Hopefully someone else can come along and confirm.

Comment: Mathematica gives 211.981 for both.

Comment: I copied both expressions into Mathematica and then adjusted the syntax of each. It evaluated both expressions as 211.981. I would check whether you have a typo somewhere in the stored procedure if you didn't copy and paste it. Normally you don't get such a large difference just from roundoff errors without any cancelation such as subtracting nearly equal 10 digit numbers to produce a single digit number, or a sum of many terms. Have you computed intermediate values?

Comment: @DouglasZare.. Yes, I did. Just copy and paste from my store procedure and from excel. That's the thing. The differences should be only in decimal rounding (probably). What do you meant computed intermediate value?

Comment: You have a complicated calculation involving a quadratic polynomial divided by a fifth degree polynomial. Break it down. Do SQL Server and Excel agree on the values for the numerator? For the denominator?

Comment: @DouglasZare.. Wow, its too far. What I need to know is, why the calculation is different between excel and sql? Which one shoud I trust? So I can make a justification/explanation about the result. Cheers,

Comment: The natural way to figure out what is going wrong in a complicated calculation is to break it into pieces. This is like stepping through code instead of trying to debug it all at a glance. Sorry if that sounds too complicated and you want to jump right to the answer.

Comment: @DouglasZare, that is ok mate. I am not a "math" guy.. But yes, what I am doing is "many calculation". And that is one of them. I feel so curious, because the result is different. How can I explain why the result is different between SQL and Excel. Since the user using excel as the main system to calculate.

Comment: If my answer solved the problem then you should accept it. If it didn't solve the problem please provide additional information.

Comment: @DouglasZare, very clear. Sorry, just got back from break. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments have speculated that this is roundoff error, and that SQL Server is more reliable because it uses more precise floats than Excel. This is wrong. The relative error is about 1%. You do not get relative errors of 1% when you perform a short computation while making roundoff errors of 10<sup>-13</sup>% unless you are subtracting nearly equal large numbers.

I suggested breaking down the computation to see if SQL Server and Excel agree on the pieces, to see where they diverged. This would have worked. It's like stepping through a program instead of just saying that the end result is not what was desired. You can do a binary search to find the problem rapidly, but the OP didn't provide any additional information.

The computation being performed is

[image: 1164.83\frac{1+17.9723+41.3364}{1+18.6685+54.4152+33.1045-3.00707+0.410853} - 459.67]

[image: = 1164.83 \frac{60.3087}{104.592}-459.67]

[image: =211.981]

There isn't any cancelation of huge numbers that might cause a large relative error. So, I tried to solve

[image: 1164.83 \frac{60.3087}{104.592+x}-459.67 = 214.630185149416]

to see what error in the denominator would result in this miscalculation. With a little calculus, I could check for typos in the constants. The solution is x=-0.410829. That's almost exactly the last term in the denominator. So, the answer isn't that one of these environments produces 1% relative errors in simple floating point calculations, it's that a term was dropped in the denominator. This would have been obvious from breaking the calculation into pieces.

The last term is the only one with something like POWER(10,-4). Could it be that this is carried out using integer arithmetic instead of floating point, so that it evaluates to 0 instead of 0.0001? Yes, [apparently that's what SQL Server does](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/using-power-function-negative-exponent). It's like 1/2=0 in integer arithmetic. If you want a decimal output you have to give it a decimal input. Cast the 10 to decimal, change it to POWER(10.0,-4), use 0.0001, or use proper scientific notation for the whole coefficient.

Comment: My gosh, there is no LaTeX support on SO, only on the other StackExchange sites. I'll edit this to make the equations readable.

Comment: The Mathematica and Math sites are the only ones with LaTex support, AFAIK.

Comment: OK, looks like Physics and the CompSci sites have it too.  So most of the hard science sites.

Comment: Yes, I suspected that SQL Server's practice of using the smallest/lowest precision datatype that can hold a literal constant without typographical loss of precision was the problem, but wasn't sure where it was.  Good job finding it.

Comment: @DouglasZare, I couldn't understand. If I declare '@myNumber' as float in storeprocedure, then I set it to POWER(2, 0.5) .. The result is 1. But I am trying to compare with excel and scientific calculator. The result is 1.4142135624. Am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Haminteu: When you write @myNumber=POWER(2,0.5), I think the right hand side is evaluated as an integer first, 1, and then cast to a float. To avoid using integer arithmetic, I think you should use @myNumber=POWER(2.0,0.5) instead.

Comment: @DouglasZare, interesting! So I need to decide how my digit after comma? hhmmm.. Is it possible just like excel? I mean, i just need to type =POWER(2, 0.5) than the result is 1.4142135624. Why in SQL needs to type the decimal first?

Comment: @Haminteu: See the link I gave in the answer. SQL Server checks for an integer first argument. Excel does not. In most programming languages, 1.0/2 is not the same as 1/2. SQL Server carries that over to the POWER function, but Excel does not. I don't think there is a deep reason for this. It's just a different convention, just as they use different syntax.

Comment: @DouglasZare, Thank you. I tried like this POWER(CAST(2 as char), 0.5) .. The result is correct.